# IncludeDirectory generate error Invalid file name for file monitoring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

### Code

```
var styleBundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/Common") { Orderer = new FileBundleOrderer(server.MapPath("/Content/bundle.txt")) }
      .IncludeDirectory("~/Content", "*.css", false);
```

### Error message:

> Invalid file name for file monitoring: '{ProjectPath}\Content'. Common
>   reasons for failure include:
>   - The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
>   - The filename is not an absolute path.
>   - The filename contains wildcard characters.
>   - The file specified is a directory.
>   - Access denied.

**'{ProjectPath}\Content'** Content directory exist in project directory!!

### Package version:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi... 1.1.0

Comment: Did you tried Include("~/Content/*.css")?